# Inkscape, shaped rectangle around curve

Tags: inkscape

I'm new to Inkscape and are planning to create a scientific poster for a conference.

I have an idea of a layout I want to use, but creating it was harder than expected:

[image]

Does anyone have an suggestion how to create the shape of 4 (or more) aligned rectangles with the inner corners shaped around a centered circle?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to learn about [path operations](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html), in particular *path difference*.

For your poster example, draw one of the rectangles, and a circle.

Duplicate the circle (<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>) so you can use it again later.

Select one of the circles and the rectangle, then apply *Path -> Difference* (<kbd>Ctrl- -</kbd>). This will subtract the circle part from the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you Juancho!

The selected items need to overlap, right?